# Why does curl return HTTP error 407 in R?

Tags: r, linux, curl, proxy, http-status-code-407

I am trying to install.packages("badger") in R 4.2.0 (ubuntu 20.04). But it says error 407 when it downloads some file:

```
.....
* installing *source* package 'gert' ...
** package 'gert' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
> curl::curl_download("https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh","get-libgit2-linux.sh")
Error in curl::curl_download("https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh",  : 
  Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
Execution halted
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lgit2
......
```

However:

- All other packages are installed perfectly fine.
- This exact file is also downloaded fine both in browser and in command line `curl https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh` both from root and user.
- This file gives the same error when i enter `curl::curl_download("https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh","index.html")` in the R prompt.
- But `curl::curl_download("https://github.com","index.html")` works fine.
- But `curl::curl_download("https://google.com","index.html")` gives the same error 407.
- When i set the proxy server with `Sys.setenv(https_proxy = )` and `Sys.setenv(https_proxy_user = )`, it does not help downloading the mentioned file with curl, moreover, the installation ends at even earlier stage saying:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package 'badger' is not available for this version of R
```

- When i unset `https_proxy` and `http_proxy` variables in bash, the installation freezes trying to download the index cos our company uses proxy server and there is no internet access without it:

```
> install.packages("badger")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
^C
```

- When i both unset the proxy settings in bash and set them in R, the curl invocation gives the same error 407, and the installation says:

```
> install.packages("badger")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection
```

What could it be and how can i get the curl working? Or how can i install the mentioned package without curl?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, it works with no errors downloading a 714 bytes file, a shell script. Note, I first tried `httr::HEAD("https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh")` and the status was 200.

Comment: A 407 error indicates you have not authenticated to a proxy server along the request path. Are you on a work network or something that uses a proxy server for http requests?

Comment: Rui Barradas httr::HEAD gives the same 407.

Comment: @MrFlick i am not sure what are you talking about, but before some day i could use internet without proxy server, and now i can not.

Answer (score 0):

**Error indicates**, proxy is not set properly or the proxy settings expired for some reasons. The latter was the case for me, on OpenSuse.

**Solution:**

- check by running `yast`, through terminal. This shall open Terminal UI view, where you can navigate to setup and test the "network proxy" and "network proxy user" settings.

OR

- [Alternately](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017441): Yast creates a file named `~/.curlrc`. Edit this, for setting your proxy and proxy-users here. Open new bash/session to validate changes.

**Test** using, `zypper refresh` command on terminal.

**NOTE** (OPTIONAL):
Other possible catch had been - some of the old repo-URLs were not reachable. which probably would need to be *disabled* until you have updated zypper as `zypper update`. For Example:

```
$ ls /etc/zypp/repos.d/
$ vi suse_update.repo
```

*<Edit, to replace `enabled=1` by `enabled=0`>*

**4MoreInfo**:

[Update Process Using Curl Does Not Access the Configured Proxy Server](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017432)

[Baseurl entries in repo files](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019926)

[SUSE Linux Enterprise : How to setup a Proxy manually](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017441)